# Detect if user leaves tab, Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I found a nice example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/v7w901oh/) that looks of for my need, and I try to implement it in my `Vuejs` app. , but till now no changes are detected and no errors with this code.

```
data() {
    return {
      tabFocus:false,
    }
}

created() {
  this.detectFocusOut();
},

watch:{
    tabFocus(value) {
      console.log("New value:", value);
    },
}

 methods:{
    detectFocusOut() {
      console.log("It is here");
      var inView = false;
      window.onfocus = window.onblur = window.onpageshow = window.onpagehide = function(
        e
      ) {
        if ({ focus: 1, pageshow: 1 }[e.type]) {
          if (inView) return;
          this.tabFocus = true;
          inView = true;
        } else if (inView) {
          this.tabFocus = !this.tabFocus;
          inView = false;
        }
      };
    },
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because the `this` in the function assigned to `window.onfocus` and etc. do not refer to the VueJS app itself, but to the `window` object. If you convert it to an arrow function it should work:

```
methods:{
    detectFocusOut() {
        console.log("It is here");
        var inView = false;
        window.onfocus = window.onblur = window.onpageshow = window.onpagehide = (e) => {
            if ({ focus: 1, pageshow: 1 }[e.type]) {
                if (inView) return;
                this.tabFocus = true;
                inView = true;
            } else if (inView) {
                this.tabFocus = !this.tabFocus;
                inView = false;
            }
        };
    },
}
```

Personally, I would advice against daisy chaining assignments. You can simply abstract all of that logic into a function:

```
methods:{
    detectFocusOut() {
        let inView = false;

        const onWindowFocusChange = (e) => {
            if ({ focus: 1, pageshow: 1 }[e.type]) {
                if (inView) return;
                this.tabFocus = true;
                inView = true;
            } else if (inView) {
                this.tabFocus = !this.tabFocus;
                inView = false;
            }
        };

        window.addEventListener('focus', onWindowFocusChange);
        window.addEventListener('blur', onWindowFocusChange);
        window.addEventListener('pageshow', onWindowFocusChange);
        window.addEventListener('pagehide', onWindowFocusChange);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Beusebiu No problem: glad to be able to help